# Marquee vertical alignment

Tags: html, alignment, vertical-alignment, marquee

I have an issue in regards the alignment of the marquee. You can see it here : www.vrobal.com Its not middle and sticking too close to the edge of the div.
[image: Marquee Problem]

I tried to use vertical-align:middle for the div, i tried to use margin-top:-10px and some other methods but they are not working fine. Any suggestion?

```
<div style=" padding:0px;">
<marquee direction="left" style="padding:0px; background:#2c74a6; height:40px; marging:0px;"><h2><span style="color:#000000">INNOVATION | IMPROVISATION | IMPLEMENTATION&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VICTORY TO GLOBAL RECYLING</span></h2></marquee></div>
```

P.S: The "&nbsp" is there to space out the 2 sentences as I need to show 2 different sentence coming out when the other is gone on the same marquee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here can do it like this

**HTML:**

```
<div style=" padding:0px;">
<marquee direction="left" style="padding:0px; background:#2c74a6; height:40px; marging:0px;">
<span class="text">INNOVATION | IMPROVISATION | IMPLEMENTATION | VICTORY TO GLOBAL RECYLING</span></marquee></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 8px;
   color: #000000;
}​
```

I recommend to you remove `<h2>` and set your `<span>` to `display: inline-block` and then with margin you can center it.

Answer (score 2):

In your styles.css you have a rule for `<h2>` (line 55). The `<h2>` element has a margin - that's your problem. Change it like this:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 40px; /* height of your marquee */
    margin: 0;
}
```